# Command in .bash_profile returns outdated result

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, bitcoin

The .bash_profile file has the alias below.

```
~# cat .bash_profile
# other commands
alias btcblock="echo $(bitcoin-cli getblockcount 2>&1)/$(wget -O - http://blockchain.info/q/getblockcount 2>/dev/null)"
```

But if I run the command and shortly thereafter the alias, the results showed are different, as below:

```
~# echo $(bitcoin-cli getblockcount 2>&1)/$(wget -O - http://blockchain.info/q/getblockcount 2>/dev/null)
503967/534428
~# btcblock
503839/534428
```

It's like the results of alias is always outdated.
Any idea why it's happening ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the command `alias btcblock="echo $(...)/$(...)"`, the two `$()`s are executed and interpolated *when the alias is defined*, because this is how `"..."` quoting works.

You probably wanted to write `alias btcblock='echo $(...)/$(...)'`, with `'` (single quotes) instead of `"` (double quotes).