# Why is my .bashrc caching curl when using as command substitution $(curl -s http://someurl.com)?

Tags: command-line, bash, curl

Here is an alias I made on my `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias rand="echo $(curl -s https://whatthecommit.com/index.txt)"
```

If you enter this url, it simply returns a random message every request, as intended.

But if you use this alias from command line:

```
rand
```

it'll always returns the same message, instead of making a new http request, as if it's caching the previous result for some reason.

BUT, if you call it directly on terminal as:

```
echo $(curl -s https://whatthecommit.com/index.txt)
```

It makes a different call every time.

Why is this happening? And how to fix it?

Comment: BTW source for whatthecommis is here: https://github.com/ngerakines/commitment  "**Enjoying https://whatthecommit.com/ ? Consider becoming a sponsor of this project. Your contributions keep the site running.**" (P.S. I do not have any connection with the owner of that project!)

Comment: Double quoting causes the alias to be evaluated at time of definition - see for example [Command in .bash_profile returns outdated result](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060878/command-in-bash-profile-returns-outdated-result)

Comment: … Probably a function would be more suitable here `rand () { echo "$(curl -s https://whatthecommit.com/index.txt)"; }`

Comment: @Raffa You're probably right, calling it as I put on my post add some delay on my terminal when I open it, I'm not sure but I think bash is evaluating it before initialize the terminal, making an http request, which is unecessary because I only want make an http request when I use the command.

Comment: @JoãoHamerski Yes, it is, you put your hand on the culprit  … It’s evaluated exactly when your terminal's running shell sources your `~/.bashrc` as you open it … That is correct … Bash expands command substitution to its output if it’s unquoted or enclosed in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
alias rand="echo \$(curl -s https://whatthecommit.com/index.txt)"
```

Will do what you want; without that `\` it will do the `$(...)` once,
when the alias is "defined", not as it is used (later, what you want).

Define the alias with both variants on the command line
and then type `alias` after each
and you will see and realize the effect.